# PHP ZipArchive skips Mac OS X files

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I used the following codes to extract a ZIP file generated by Mac OS X.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open('tmp/archive.zip') === TRUE) {
  // delete all files in temp output folder
  $files = glob(ABS_PATH . 'tmp/output/*');
  foreach($files as $f) {
    if(is_file($f)) {
      unlink($f);
    }
  }
  $zip->extractTo('tmp/output/');
  $zip->close();
  unlink('tmp/archive.zip');
}
```

The Zip archive is extracted successfully, however the `extractTo()` function encounters permission denied when the function attempts to extract files & folder starts with `.` (e.g.`.MAC_OSX` folder generated by Mac OSX).

How do I skip those files & folders?

From the [extractTo()](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php) documentation, it only supports specifying files to extract, instead of an exclusion list.

p.s. my server is Ubuntu server, PHP 5.3